# ошибка exc.MissingGreenlet

Tags: postgresql, aiogram, sqlalchemy, aiohttp

при вызове функции

```
async def create_company(session, user_id, comp_data: dict):
    try:
        new_company = Company(comp_name=comp_data['comp_name'],
                              inn=comp_data['inn'],
                              user_id=user_id)
        session.add(new_company)
        await session.flush()
        await session.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error creating company: {e}")
```

в коде:

```
async def getting_comp_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(inn=message.text)
    await message.reply('Регистрация завершена, спасибо! '
                        'Для получения статуса груза воспользуйтесь командой /status.')
    data = await state.get_data()
    user_id = data['user_id']
    print(data)

    async with sessionmanager.session() as session:
        # Создаем пользователя
        user_data = {
            'phone_number': data['phone_number'],
            'name': data['name'],
            'user_id': data['user_id']
        }
        user = await create_user(user_data, session)

        # Проверяем, что пользователь успешно создан
        if user:
            # Создаем компанию, используя user.id
            comp_data = {
                'comp_name': data['comp_name'],
                'inn': data['inn']
            }
            await create_company(session, user.id, comp_data)
        else:
            logging.error("User creation failed.")

    await state.clear()
```

получаю ошибку: raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)
как исправить?